# Pagination with backbone.js and node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, pagination

```
i am having data in mongodb.
```

i have to show per page only 10 data .

i don't have idea about pagination so how to show that using pagination.

i am using backbone.js and node.js and mongodb.

how to implement and take me proper way.Give some link and coding to understand and also to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing pagination is quite trivial.

**Client side:**

```
ChairCollection collection = new ChairCollection();
...
collection.fetch({page:1, limit:10});
```

**Server side (Assuming the you use express.js and mongoose):**

```
app.get("/chairs", function(req,res){
  var page = req.query.page;
  var limit = req.query.limit;
  Animal.find({}).skip((page - 1)*limit).limit(limit).exec(function(err,chairs){
    res.send(chairs);
  })
})
```